# How to get the Object details of the next row when clicking on a button in the first row?

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with Model details on each row and i want to exchange values of two Objects when a button on a row is clicked. 
For example: an Object of name "Activity1" has order number"1" 
                Object of name "Activity2" has order number "2"

I want to press a button on the row of Activity 1 which exchange the order numbers, so that Activity 1 would have order number "2" and Activity 2 would have order number "1".

I was able to get the details of The object of the row pressed on and change it for what i want but i am not able to get the details of the next row to change it as well, any help?

The code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<WEB02.ConfigurationModel.TestGrid>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{

    columns.Bound(o => o.Name).Width(110);
    columns.Bound(o => o.Type).Width(130);
    columns.Command(command => {command.Destroy();

    command.Custom("Higher Order").Click("HigherOrder");

     });
})
.Sortable()
.Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Virtual(true))
.Selectable(selectable => selectable
        .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Name))
    .PageSize(100)
    .Read(read => read.Action("ActivityGrid", "Configuration"))
    .Destroy("TestDelete", "Configuration")
    .Events(events => events.Sync("sync_handler"))       
    )


    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true))

)
```

function

```
function HigherOrder(e) {
    var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr");    // get the current table row (tr)
    var item = this.dataItem(tr);
    // get the date of this row
    //console.log(item);
    console.log(item.NodeId);
    console.log(item.Type);
    console.log(item);
    var newOrder= parseInt(item.ActivOrderNo)+1;
    var params = {

        nodeID: item.NodeId + ".CONFIG.OrderNumber",
        write: newOrder
    };

    console.log(newOrder);
    var temp = {
        url: "/Configuration/WriteAttribute",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        success: function (params) {
            window.location.replace(params.redirect);
        }
    };
    $.ajax(temp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get next row, you need to use `row.index` property.

To get current row index:

```
var grid = $('[name="Grid"]').data("kendoGrid");        
var dataRows = grid.items();
var rowIndex = dataRows.index(grid.select());
```

To get data item by index use next code snipet:

```
var nextDataItem = grid.dataItems()[rowIndex+1];
```

Comment: I think it will work but for now it is giving me an error with the kendo grid. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined. Any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe that caused by wrong selector. Update my answer.

Comment: Actually the old selector was right, and i had to put the Selectable part for it to work (check the updated question). But now i have another problem, the selected rowIndex appears to be always -1, not the row details !!

Comment: In your function `HigherOrder` try to pass `item` into `index()` method:      `var rowIndex = dataRows.index(item);` May be on button click grid item is not selecting

Comment: yes it is exactly like that, when the button is clicked the row is not selected. Although it is selected when using Destroy function, but this is an already built function in kendo Grid

Comment: Thats ok i think, just call my code in `HigherOrder` function

Comment: Done that but the grid.dataItems(rowIndex+1) grabs the whole grid items not only the next row!

Comment: try `grid.dataItems()[rowIndex+1]`

Comment: Thanks, that made the job, please update the answer :)